# VS Code Windows C++ cannot include Header files even though added to tasks.json with -I option

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In a C++ project, I have a folder such as 
/projectFolder 
|
|->executables
|
|->src

I have some .cpp files with main function under executables folder. These files include some header files under src folder. Under src folder, there are subfolders and all header files should be included to files under executables.

I tried to adjust my tasks.json as this

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "{absolute path to src folder}\\src"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

However, when I run the cpp under executable directory, it still gives warning that header files cannot be found. I also suspect that it cannot compile the cpp files under src directory as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to hack at least TWO files to get VS Code to know where the headers are. tasks.json tells VS Code to  tell the compiler where to look. c_cpp_properties.json tells VS Code to tell the Intellisense code analysis module where to look.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried that one as well like this `"includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "abolutepath\\src\\**"]` but still running cpp gives errors.

Comment: Grab the build command generated by VS Code from the console and pop it into a command prompt or powershell window.  If you get the same result, study the command and make sure the paths make sense. Of they don't correct them and build again. Repeat until you can build from the command line. Then study the difference between what you use and what VSCode generates. Maybe you'll see how to kick VS Code into submission, but if not, add your command and VS Code's to the question and odds are good someone here will spot the problem.

Comment: why aren't you using `${workspaceFolder}` for your include path flag?

Comment: @starball I tried just adding the root directory for all project and also thing I stated. But I couldn't make it find header files under subdirectories. Thus, the only solution I found is including all subdirectories to `-I` option like this `"-I","..\\src\\geometry\\primitives","-I","..\\src\\interface"` inside tasks.json. It works like this but I also had to give exact *.cpp files to compile. I do not think that this is the best solution but it works

Comment: you have multiple cpp files that need to be linked together? then why do you only list one (the current) source file in your compile command?

Comment: @starball I thought specifying the source folder for all include values via -I was enough to include those header files and also their cpp files where everything is implemented. Apparently, I was wrong but I've never worked on such a project before and this project was given to me to work on it. I thought -I was recursively includes all necessary files